# I need an input with strings in C

Tags: c

i need to read strings from file in C, and that's work, now i need to find in each string the words that start with a capital letter. Any input?

Example: 1) Windows is a good OS 2) Linux is Open Source

Words with capital letter: Windows, OS, Linux, Open, Source.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  /* dichiarazioni variabili */

  FILE *fp;
  char vet1[100];
  char vet2[100];

  fp = fopen("file.txt", "r"); /* apro il file contenente la stringa */

  if (fp == NULL) {
    printf("\nIl file non esiste!\n");
  }

  while (!feof(fp)) {
    fgets(vet1, 100, fp);
    printf("%s\n", vet1);
  }

  fclose(fp);
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. What code have you written to try to solve this problem yourself?

Comment: I thought of taking the vector containing the string and comparing the first letter with the next, as soon as it recognizes the capital letter, it writes the word that contains it.

Comment: I can't use string lib :(

Comment: So, i'll write something like this: vet1[pos]>='A' && vet2[pos]<='Z' and with a cicle for I scroll the vector and compare

Comment: You should try your idea and if it's not working, post the code here. Then we can have a look and see what might be wrong. But don't expect us to write the whole code for you.

Comment: Absolute not, i only need an input..

Comment: you could use regular expressions : http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/regex.3.html

Comment: [`while (!feof(fp))`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feoffile-always-wrong) is always wrong

Answer (score 1):

Detect a Capital letter is as simple as read the "ascii" manual in any GNU / Linux distro where you can find that all  capital tetters from A to Z has a hex number from 0x40 to 0x5A respectivily with this in mind:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int main( int argc,char *argv[])
{
  char *buffer,c;
  size_t bufsize = 32; // add all the buffer that you need
  size_t characters;
  FILE *fp;
  if(argc != 2)
    return -1;
  buffer = (char *)malloc(bufsize * sizeof(char));
  fp = fopen(argv[1],"r");
  if( fp == NULL)
     return -2;
  while( !feof(fp) )
  {
    characters = getline(&buffer,&bufsize,fp);
    buffer[characters-1]='\0';
    if ( buffer[0] > 0x40 && buffer[0] < 0x5A )
        printf("buffer = %s",buffer);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is this: if(argv[1][0] == '\0') ? And Malloc function (?) P.S: Thank's a lot!! PPS: I can't use stdlib.h library.

Comment: argv[1][0] is the first char of argv[1]  and '\0' is the null termination caracter like simple NULL and if(argv[1][0] == '\0')  is to be sure that need a file as input.
Glad I could help. Feel free to [accept this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) if you found it useful.

Comment: Your argv construct is just bad. If you want to determine the existence of command line arguments use argc.

Comment: @datell thanks for your recomentation I've just edited .